# PHP wrapping last two letters of string with HTML

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am running into a problem trying to do a replacement on a few strings. Essentially what I have is a bunch of prices on my page that look like

**<sup>RMB</sup>148.00**

What i am trying to do is run a replace on only the last 2 numbers so i can do something like

**<sup>RMB</sup>148<sup>00</sup>**

Preg replace works fine for the RMB part because it is always there.

My problem is the last two numbers can be anything it all depends on the price so I cant just remove and replace, I need to just wrap HTML `<sup>` tags around them.

```
$string = $product['price'];
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);
echo preg_replace('/RMB/', '<sup class="currency-sym">RMB</sup>', $string, 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the last two characters are digits, you could just

```
$string=preg_replace('/(\d\d)$/', '<sup class="currency-sym">\1</sup>', $string);
```

If not,

```
$string=preg_replace('/(..)$/', '<sup class="currency-sym">\1</sup>', $string);
```

should do the trick.

Alternativly use

```
$string=substr($string,0,-2).'<sup class="currency-sym">'.substr($string,-2).'</sup>';
```

Comment: @NooBskie, if u need explanation, follow my answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex solution that looks for the final digit notation at the end of your string.

```
$string = 'RMB148.00';
$string = preg_replace('/(\d+)\.(\d{2})\z/','$1<sup>$2</sup>',$string);
echo $string;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Code.

```
<?php

$string = '14842.00';
$string = substr($string, 0, strlen($string) - 2) . '<sup>' . substr($string, strlen($string) - 2, 2) . '</sup>';

echo $string;
```

[Try online sandbox](http://code.runnable.com/VlURvka8LjI9YuLP/php-wrapping-last-two-letters-of-string-with-html).

### Explanation.

`substr($s, $i, $l)` gets `$l` symbols of `$s`, started from `$i` index (indexes starts from zero).

So first `substr($string, 0, strlen($string) - 2)` gets all string except last two symbols.

Second `substr($string, strlen($string) - 2, 2)` gets only last two symbols.

[More about substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following with the explode () function

```
$string = explode ('.', $product['price']);

$new_string = $string[0].'<sup>'. $string [1]. '</sup>';
```

And do the regex for the RMB the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a pattern matching regex. Note the `$1` in the replacement argument matches `(\d{2})` in the pattern argument. `preg_replace()` only replaces the matched pattern. This pattern matches `.` followed  by any two digits. Since `.` is not included in the replacement argument it does not show up in your `$string`.

```
$string = preg_replace('/\.(\d{2})$/', '<sup>$1</sup>', $string);
```

Of course, you could use one preg_replace to do what you want:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^(RMB)(\d+)(\.(\d{2}))?$/', "<sup class='currency-sym'>$1</sup>$2<sup>$4</sup>", $string);
```

The second example may be a good idea if you want DOM integrity, otherwise it creates an empty `<sup></sup>` when there is no decimal.